# Importing Excel Spreadsheet into Access using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Creates Duplicates

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am coming across a very unexpected issue in that I have an excel spreadsheet that I am importing into a Microsoft Access database using: `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. It seemed to work fine... but now that I am down to the final phase of my project and am beginning to calculate the data imported... I noticed that all the calculations are exactly double of what they should be. The culprit turned out to be from a very surprising source!

It turns out it is duplicating almost every record when I import using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. Out of a 4000 row spreadsheet, my created Access table has 7998 rows. In researching this issue I've come across multiple suggestions of how to delete the duplicates after you have imported them. This is simply not a solution in my case because my data has duplicate rows within in it that I need to preserve.

In short I need to import the spreadsheet exactly as it sits duplicate rows and all... but without the import process creating additional duplicates. It seems that this should be a very basic process and am really curious to know how this import process is creating duplicate rows to begin with? I mean really it should only import what data is there!

It's crunch time on a tight deadline and I didn't count on this surprising issue... so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here is the offending line of code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTableName, strFileName, True
```

I do not think it matters... but I am using an Open File Dialog to acquire the spreadsheet. I can post the full procedure if anyone thinks it will help though.

For further clarification here is my full code for this procedure. PLEASE NOTE that I am changing the name of the table from the imported file name into my own enumerated name as I am importing several sheets at a time.

```
Private Sub ImportFiles()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strTableName As String
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim lngProcessID As Long

CancelProcessing = False
' Set up the File Dialog. '
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog
   ' Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box '
   .AllowMultiSelect = True

   ' Set the title of the dialog box. '
 .Title = "Select files to import"
 .Filters.Clear
 .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 1
 .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsl", 2
 .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls", 3
 .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.accdb", 4
 .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.mdb", 5
   ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the '
   ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns '
   ' False, the user clicked Cancel. '
   If .Show = True Then
    lngProcessID = OpenCustomLoader()
        CountOfFiles = 0
      ' Validate That All Fields Have Been Mapped
      For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
        If CancelProcessing = False Then
           CountOfFiles = CountOfFiles + 1
           strTableName = "tblImport" & CountOfFiles
           strFileName = .SelectedItems(CountOfFiles)
           ' Import Table Into Access
           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTableName, strFileName, True
         Call ValidateFields(strTableName)
         If CancelProcessing = True Then DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strTableName
        End If
      Next
        ' Prime File Count
        CountOfFiles = 0
      'Loop through each file selected and add it to our list box. '
      If CancelProcessing = False Then
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
           CountOfFiles = CountOfFiles + 1
           strTableName = "tblImport" & CountOfFiles
           strFileName = .SelectedItems(CountOfFiles)
           ' Import Table Into Access
           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTableName, strFileName, True
           DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", CurrentDb.TableDefs("dbo_tblStagingTable").Connect, acTable, strTableName, strTableName
           Call ImportFileData(strTableName)
        Next
        Call CopyStagingToInterests
      End If
      Call CloseCustomLoader(lngProcessID)
      Call CloseCustomLoader(lngProcessID)
   End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: It should not be duplicating it. Can you check your code and ensure that the offending line is running only once?

Comment: Good point Siddharth... Yes, I've double checked. In stepping through the code line by line... Immediately after the Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet... their is multiple records. The spreadsheets I am importing are test sheets that originally contained 12,197 rows... but I broke them up into three sheets at 4000 rows a piece to test multiple importing... do you think it's possible that the sheets themselves became corrupted?

Comment: +1... My deepest apologies. You are absolutely correct. I am importing the same table twice... once to do a validation that all of the necessary "Mapped" fields are present... and the second time actually imports the data if the Mapped fields are present. I actually delete the table object after the first import... but I had placed criteria which prevented it from deleting... thus the duplicates. I would vote this as the answer... but you put it in a comment...  so all I can do is up vote it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :D

Comment: @HansUp: "Can you check your code and ensure that the offending line is running only once?" is perfect for a comment ;)

Comment: @HansUp: On a serious note, I would recommend that you add that in your answer. If you allow me, I want to make a small change in your post so that it becomes a valid answer

Comment: @HansUp. Yes however you think this is best handled please let me know and I will do what I can.

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs I think we're covered now.  But you're still welcome to submit a better answer based on the details of your experience.  And accept that one.  I got upvotes, so got nothing to complain about.  :-)  I pruned away my obsolete comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: I submitted this answer before we understood the true cause of the problem.  Skip to **Post Mortem** for the explanation.  I'll leave the rest of this answer in place because querying a spreadsheet with a connection string embedded in the query's `FROM` clause is a useful technique which should help future readers.

I don't understand why `TransferSpreadsheet` is duplicating your spreadsheet data. It may help to show us more of the context from your VBA procedure which uses `TransferSpreadsheet`, but probably not the whole thing.

Meanwhile, considering your time frame is tight, create an Access query to fetch the worksheet data.

Here is an example tested on my Access 2010 system:

```sql
SELECT s1.*
FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\temp.xls].[Sheet1$] AS s1
```

If you create a similar query, and it returns only the data you want (no extra duplicates), you can then convert it to an "append query" and add that data to a suitable existing table. This would also imply that the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` is returning the right results and you need to check if that piece of code is being run more than once.

A quick way to figure out the embedded connection string is to create a link to the worksheet.  Then you can inspect the link properties to get what you need for the query:

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblExcelData").Connect
Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\share\Access\temp.xls
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblExcelData").SourceTableName
Sheet1$
```

After you collect that information, you don't need to keep the link in order for the query to work.  On the other hand, if you can keep the link, the query could be even simpler.

**Post Mortem**:

Anthony discovered the code called `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport` twice for the same set of options.  So each spreadsheet's data was unintentionally imported twice.

Comment: Thank you for this... I thought for sure your select statement would produce the same duplicates... but it didn't? It actually produced the exact amount of records which is making me believe that I am doing something incorrect in my Docmd.Transferspreadsheet. For clarification I've inserted all of the code in the procedure as it isn't all that much... but would be very interested to know if you see anything that may be causing this problem? Thanks

Comment: My hunch is somehow you're running `Transferspreadsheet` with the same set of options more than once, as @Siddharth suggested.  Unfortunately I have no idea how or why that happens.

Comment: Hold the phone!  Looking again, I see `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, ...` twice.

Comment: +1 Yes... you are both correct. Please see my comment above. My deepest apologies and sorry for wasting your time... it was my logic after all... but I must admit that your fresh set of eyes helped!

Comment: @SiddharthRout  Thanks!  Collaborating with you is always a positive experience for me.